# Subset question involving a complement. Got me stuck.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Working in Halmos' Naive Set Theory.

Prove that:
$$A\cap B\subset (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C')$$

So far my only thought is to go element chasing.

Proof: Suppose $x\in A\cap B$. That is to say, $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. We will show that $x\in(A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C')$.

I don't know what opening I need from here. $A\cap B$ doesn't seem strong enough to move to the RHS.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options: either $x\in C$ or $x\in C'$. You need to prove that at least one of the following is true: $x\in A\cap C$ or $x\in B\cap C'$. Can you continue?

Comment: Oh duh! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

$$
A\cap B=A\cap B\cap (C\cup C')=(A\cap B\cap C)\cup (A\cap B\cap  C')\subset(A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C')
$$